# composite primary key and autoincrement column but NOT primary key

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_result` (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `year`, `result`) 
VALUES (%f, %f, %d, %d, %f)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE result=%f;
```

These are results of a realtime calculator that I want to uniquely store in the tbl_result database table, and maintain updated even if the calculation result changes. The above seems to me like the best way to do this.

However for this to work `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `year` must be primary keys:

```
CREATE  TABLE `tbl_result` (
  `ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `var1` DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `var2` DECIMAL(3,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `var3` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `year` INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `result` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `year`) 
);
```

But because I also need to store a unique id to cross reference results with multiple users. I get the following error:

Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

MySql version is 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, is it possible to set the default of a column with a guid value?

Thanks,
P.

P.S. this sounds like a plausible scenario to me, is it possible to report a suggestion to MySql?

Comment: Why can't you just change your current `PRIMARY KEY` to a `UNIQUE` constraint?

Comment: MySQL does not have real sequences. If you can switch to another database which has sequences (PostgreSQL, Oracle) or identities (MSSQL), you can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to this is using the `ID` as your primary key, and the `var1, var2, var3, year` fields as an alternate key by using an `UNIQUE KEY` constraint

So, your table definition shall look like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE `tbl_result` (
  `ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `var1` DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `var2` DECIMAL(3,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `var3` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `year` INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `result` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `year`) 
);
```

The `UNIQUE KEY` constraint will prevent from duplicate insertions of your fields.