# What is the best way to have a varchar primary key column with an auto-increment?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, primary-key

I would like to create some tables in MySQL. One table would be for users, one for topics, one for comments, and so on.

I need each table to have its own ID column in the following format:

```
USERS table: ID column
Values: 
USR00001
USR00002
USR00003
..
..
USR99999
```

where as topics table would have IDs like:

```
TPC00001
TPC00002
TPC00003
```

similarly, the comments table would have the following IDs:

```
CMT00001
CMT00002
```

I tried to use UNIQUE key but did not work: (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500712/composite-primary-key-and-autoincrement-column-but-not-primary-key))

```
CREATE  TABLE `users` (
  `ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
  UNIQUE KEY ( 'USR' + `ID`) 
);
```

Can it be done using triggers (Before Insert) maybe?

Please note that I don't want to handle the insertion of the primary keys on the application level. I would prefer the database engine to handle all the work for that.

Comment: Having varchar as PK is bad idea in normal case. So you're asking about "least evil" (because of "best solution" from "bad practice"). If you want to have unique index on varchar - then have it, but add surrogate integer PK to identify row

Comment: but why bother?  Just use simple IDs, then when you retrieve the data prepend the `USR` or `TPC` etc

Comment: totally agree with @user2310289 or you can have a new column that will contain the prefix of your ID if `USR` or `TPC` depending to your preferences

Comment: Also, if you need just prefix - then use two columns. Prefixes in first and number in second. That would be composite key - and certainly you'll be able to have auto_increment on integer part

Comment: Reeeeeeeally just don't. You say you need it but your really don't. With the above examples you don't even need composite keys.